# How to find a value and replace it using Regex in NiFi?

Tags: regex, string, apache-nifi, regex-group, regex-greedy

I need to find values and replace values using regex in apache NiFi.

I have a file as below:

```
[{
   "s1":"s2",
   "s2":"s3",
 },
 {
   "d1":"d2",
   "d3":"d4",
  },
```

i need to find values when ever `,
                            }`

my expected output should be

```
[{
   "s1":"s2",
   "s2":"s3"
 },
 {
   "d1":"d2",
   "d3":"d4"
  }]
```

I have tried this but not working

```
value:- (,\n})
replace value :- }
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can likely do that using this expression:

```
("),(\s*})
```

and replacing it with:

```
$1$2
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rMRNrW/1/)